# Ghostscript Merge pdf and create table of content page from merged files

Tags: pdf, merge, ghostscript, tableofcontents

I would like to generate a PDF file with a table of content based on the merged files.

Let's say that I have these files: `1.pdf`, `2.pdf` and `3.pdf`.

I would love to create a fourth PDF file containing the list with internal links to the different merged files.

Let's name it: `toc.pdf`. It should contain the list of the previous files with a pdfmark to link on the document.

I have succeeded merging the first three documents with the **Ghostscript** command:

```
gs -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dEPSFitPage -o merged.pdf 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf
```

But I have failed looking for options on how to build the file `toc.pdf` with the internal links.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1:

```
gs -o 1_toc.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/Title (1.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" -f 1.pdf

gs -o 2_toc.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/Title (2.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" -f 2.pdf

gs -o 3_toc.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/Title (3.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" -f 3.pdf
```

Step 2:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=toc.pdf 1_toc.pdf 2_toc.pdf 3_toc.pdf
```

Comment: That's fantastic. you saved me an hour of GS research!

Answer (score 4):

OK first point; GS and the pdfwrite device aren't intended for this purpose.

I've explained this before, but it bears repetition because people don't understand how this system works and therefore aren't aware of the potential pitfalls. You aren't 'merging' files at all, when you process a PDF file with GS it is fully interpreted and broken down into a sequence of graphics primitive. These are then transferred to a 'device' which deals with them, often this renders the graphics to a bitmap but in the case of pdfwrite it reassembles them into a *brand new* PDF file.

So the final PDF file is not created by chopping up the bits of the original file and rearranging them, its a totally newly created file which has the same appearance.

Now as to your actual request. If you want to do this you are going to have to do it manually, I don't think there is any tool which is going to do this for you.

The good news is that GS *does* accept and process most pdfmarks, so you can create a pdfmark, or series of them, which will do what you want. Of course, you are going to have to craft these specifically for each case, as you will need to know the page number within the final file as part of the pdfmark which means knowing how many pages are in each of the component files.

By the way, the EPSFitPage switch has no effect on any input which is not a well-formed EPS file. If you want to fit PDF files, use PDFFitPage.

Answer (score 1):

expanding KenS answer, from this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.pdf/TslRCZH6x70/X_veyNNMyTcJ

assuming the `1.pdf`, `2.pdf` and `3.pdf` all have 3 pages, you can try:

```
gs -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -c "[/Page 1 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title (file 1.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" \
  -c "[/Page 4 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title (file 2.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" \
  -c "[/Page 7 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title (file 3.pdf) /OUT pdfmark" \
  -f merged.pdf
```

Of course, you shoud chage the number after `/Page` and the string in the brackets after `/Title`.